# How to update multiple rows based on join query

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update, subquery

I have two Oracle tables

```
Table A
----------
Fst_nm | Lst_nm | UserID | AppID 

Table B
----------
Fst_nm | Lst_nm | UserID | AppID
```

Some people exist in both tables, some only exist in one. 
Some people exist in both tables but do not have an AppID in table A. 
I am trying to write a query to join these two tables, determine who does not have an AppID in Table A but DOES have an AppID in table B, and copy that same AppID to Table A.
(The cases don't match in these tables so a little extra finessing is necessary.)

Here's what I have so far:

```
UPDATE TABLE_A a
SET a.AppID = (SELECT b.AppID
                 FROM TABLE_A a
                 JOIN TABLE_B b
                 ON trim(upper(a.lst_nm))  = trim(upper(b.lst_nm))
                 AND trim(upper(a.fst_nm)) = trim(upper(b.fst_nm)) 
                 WHERE a.Appid is null
                 AND a.UserID IS NOT null
                 AND b.fst_nm IS NOT NULL
                 AND b.lst_nm IS NOT NULL)
WHERE a.AppID is null;
```

And I am understandably receiving this error:
`ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`

I can go through and write individual update statements based on the SELECT query, but it's ~150 records and would like to get it done in one query.

Any tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be selecting again from `table_a` in the subquery - instead, you want to correlate it with the outer query. To check if there is a relevant match in `table_b`, you can use an `exists`  condition.

I *think* that the logic you want is:

```
update table_a a
set a.appid = (
    select b.appid
    from table_b b
    where
        trim(upper(a.lst_nm))  = trim(upper(b.lst_nm))
        and trim(upper(a.fst_nm)) = trim(upper(b.fst_nm)) 
        and b.fst_nm is not null
        and b.lst_nm is not null
)
where 
    a.appid is null 
    and a.userid is not null
    and exists (
        select 1
        from table_b b
        where 
            trim(upper(a.lst_nm))  = trim(upper(b.lst_nm))
            and trim(upper(a.fst_nm)) = trim(upper(b.fst_nm)) 
            and b.fst_nm is not null
            and b.lst_nm is not null
    )
```